# xsd: define an element that can be repeated an even number of times

Tags: xsd

with xsd, is there a way in which we can define an element that is repeated an even number of times? with my information it is not possible with the attributes minOcurs and maxOccurs.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<xs:element name="A">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="?" minOccurs="?"/>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>  
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2"/>
  </xs:sequence>
```

Comment: @user3613893 See the update. `B` can occur 0, 2, 4, 6. I know what "even" means. :)

Comment: thank you very much, but what are the changes that i do if i want the element can occur an odd number of times?

Comment: lexicore answered your original question correctly and deserves an upvote and acceptance.  Clearly you can extend his answer to get an odd number of times by following one *required* `B` element by his answer allowing 0, 2, 4 or more `B` elements.

Comment: yes, you are right. <xs:sequence> <xs:element name="B" /> <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2"/>.</xs:sequence> </xs:sequence>. . thank you guys

Comment: @kjhughes I'm not really "award-oriented" :), but thank you for your words, it is very nice of you.