# extending existing complexType

Tags: xsd

this topic is related to [xsd: define an element that can be repeated an even number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192211/xsd-define-an-element-that-can-be-repeated-an-even-number-of-times/27192281?noredirect=1#comment42870883_27192281). i would like to create a new complex type using complexContent with extension. i tried this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

<xs:complexType name="evenOccurrence">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>  

<xs:complexType name="oddOcurrence">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="evenOccurrence">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="B"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

this code generate the following error: *cos-nonambig: B and B (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.*. how i can fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are two similar ways of doing it:

1- Without extension:

```
<xs:complexType name="oddOcurrence">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B" /> <!-- 1 time -->
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <!-- 2n times -->
            <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

2- Similar, with extension

```
<xs:complexType name="elementOneTime">
    <xs:sequence>
        <!-- 1 time -->
        <xs:element name="B" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="oddOcurrence">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="elementOneTime">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <!-- 2n times -->
                <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

**EDIT:** ¿Why was it ambiguous?

As *evenOccurrence* can be empty, when the parser finds the first *B element* of and *oddOccurance*, it doesn't know if its parsing the first B of an *evenOccurance* or the *B element* that only appears once.

By putting first the element that can only appear once you remove the ambiguity, as the first *B element* would be analyzed and then the parser would enter in a state in which it would analyze the *oddOccurence* type (all the other B elements).